# how to combine output (list) with positions of values under corresponding variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

How to combine a list with values, list with the number of the variable where the value belongs to and the variable names to one data frame?

For example:

```
outp <- c(1:10)
posp <- c(1,1,1,3,3,5,5,6,6,10)
namesp <- c('var1','var2','var3','var4','var5','var6','var7','var8','var9','var10')
```

Output should be that values of `outp` will be in a df under the variable that is referred to in `posp` in combination with `namesp` (where var1 corresponds to 1, var2 corresponds to 2, etc.).

So the df has three rows with var1 containing the values 1,2 and 3, var2 is empty, var3 has 4 and 5, etc.

I tried to create a df but cannot get the positions of the values right.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a table or data of the desired output? I am having trouble accurately interpreting the logic behind "outpout should be that 1,2,3 will be under var1, 4,5 under var3, etc." - could you clarify how this is derived from `outp` and `posp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a two-column dataframe specifying which values should be in which column, then `complete` the full set of column names from `var1` to `var10` to fill in missing columns names (e.g. `var2`, `var4` etc.). Finally reshape to a wide format. The final `select` operation is only for reordering the columns to match the column order in `namesp`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

enframe(setNames(outp, namesp[posp])) %>% 
  complete(name = namesp) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number(), .by = name) %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  select(all_of(namesp))

# A tibble: 3 × 10
   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8  var9 var10
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    NA     4    NA     6     8    NA    NA    NA    10
2     2    NA     5    NA     7     9    NA    NA    NA    NA
3     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(purrr)

nrows <- max(table(posp))
set_names(readr::parse_number(namesp), namesp) |>
  map(~ `length<-`(outp[which(posp == .x)], nrows)) |>
  as.data.frame()
```

1. `set_names` creates a named vector where the names are "var1", "var2", etc. and the values are the numbers extracted from the names (1, 2, ...). Doing it this way will return the same results if `namesp` is out of order.
2. We iterate over this named vector using `map`, which will preserve the element names. Using the base R function `which`, we get the indices from `posp` that match that iteration (e.g., `which(prop == 1)`, `which(prop == 2)`) and use those indices to get the corresponding values from `outp`.
3. One key trick here is that the lengths of these vectors are not equal. We set them all to be the same length using `length<-` assignment function.
4. Lastly we simply convert the named list into a data frame.

---

Here is a pretty fast base R option:

```r
idx <- c(namesp[posp], namesp[-posp])
length(outp) <- length(idx)
data.frame(do.call(cbind, tapply(outp, idx, `length<-`, max(rle(posp)[[1]]))[namesp]))
```

**Benchmark**

```r
base_split <- function() {
  splt <- setNames(split(outp, factor(posp, 1:10)), namesp)
  as.data.frame(lapply(splt, "[", 1:max(lengths(splt))))
}

base_tapply <- function() {
  idx <- c(namesp[posp], namesp[-posp])
  length(outp) <- length(idx)
  data.frame(do.call(cbind, tapply(outp, idx, `length<-`, max(rle(posp)[[1]]))[namesp]))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base_split(),
  base_tapply(),
  setup = {
    outp <- c(1:10)
    posp <- c(1,1,1,3,3,5,5,6,6,10)
    namesp <- c('var1','var2','var3','var4','var5','var6','var7','var8','var9','var10')
  },
  control = list(warmup = 5L)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#           expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval cld
#   base_split() 633.3 650.10 689.546 658.05 706.20 1032.7   100  a 
#  base_tapply() 268.7 277.45 292.599 281.30 304.75  440.6   100   b
```

**Output**

```
   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8  var9 var10
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    NA     4    NA     6     8    NA    NA    NA    10
2     2    NA     5    NA     7     9    NA    NA    NA    NA
3     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R using split:

```
splt <- setNames(split(outp, factor(posp, 1:10)), namesp)
as.data.frame(lapply(splt, "[", 1:max(lengths(splt))))
#>   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10
#> 1    1   NA    4   NA    6    8   NA   NA   NA    10
#> 2    2   NA    5   NA    7    9   NA   NA   NA    NA
#> 3    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

### Benchmark

Setup:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

fBase <- function(outp, posp, namesp) {
  splt <- setNames(split(outp, factor(posp, 1:10)), namesp)
  as.data.frame(lapply(splt, "[", 1:max(lengths(splt))))
}

fTidy <- function(outp, posp, namesp) {
  enframe(setNames(outp, namesp[posp])) %>% 
    complete(name = namesp) %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number(), .by = name) %>% 
    pivot_wider() %>% 
    select(all_of(namesp))
}

fPurrr <- function(outp, posp, namesp) {
  nrows <- tail(sort(table(posp)), 1)
  set_names(readr::parse_number(namesp), namesp) |>
    map(~ `length<-`(outp[which(posp == .x)], nrows)) |>
    as.data.frame()
}
```

Check equivalency:

```
all.equal(fBase(outp, posp, namesp), as.data.frame(fTidy(outp, posp, namesp)))
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(fBase(outp, posp, namesp), fPurrr(outp, posp, namesp))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Timings:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base = fBase(outp, posp, namesp),
  tidy = fTidy(outp, posp, namesp),
  purrr = fPurrr(outp, posp, namesp)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>   expr      min         lq      mean     median        uq       max neval
#>   base  380.301   413.5510   481.700   440.7500   499.801  2722.201   100
#>   tidy 9709.501 10637.1010 11272.364 11000.0515 11454.050 17372.901   100
#>  purrr  807.300   885.8015  1049.957   959.3515  1041.551  4293.602   100
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(outp, posp, namesp) 

df %>% 
  mutate(nfromnamesp = str_remove(namesp, "var") %>% as.numeric()) %>% 
  left_join(df, by = c("nfromnamesp" = "posp")) %>% 
  transmute(namesp = namesp.x, outp = outp.y) %>% 
  group_by(namesp) %>% 
  summarise(
    outp = list(c(outp, rep(NA, 3-n()))),
    ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = namesp, values_from = outp) %>% 
  unnest(everything()) %>% 
  select(paste0("var", names(.) %>% str_remove("var") %>% order()))
    
# A tibble: 3 × 10
   var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8  var9 var10
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    NA     4    NA     6     8    NA    NA    NA    10
2     2    NA     5    NA     7     9    NA    NA    NA    NA
3     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```